# What is wrong with my recursive method for getting binary from int?

Tags: java, recursion

So I am supposed to make a method that takes in an integer and recursively creates a string that is the representation in binary form. Here is what I have so far. It does not work correctly. When I pass in the number 13, I receive a "1" as the result instead of "1101"

```
public String convBinary(int n) {
   if( n < 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed precondition: convBinary. n must be >= 0. n: " + n);

   String result="";

   if(n<2){
       result=Integer.toString(n);
       return result;
   }
   else{
       if(n!=0){

           convBinary((n/2));
           result+=Integer.toString(n%2);
       }
   }
   return result; 
}
```

Comment: convBinary((n/2)); you're interested in what this line returns. You're ignoring it!

Comment: `convBinary((n/2));` <-- you ignore the value returned by `convBinary`.

Comment: or use Integer.toBinaryString directly.

Answer (score 3):

You are supposed to add the result of the recursive call to the result :

```
       result = convBinary((n/2));
       result += Integer.toString(n%2);
```

And you can write this with less lines :

```
public String convBinary(int n) {
   if( n < 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed precondition: convBinary. n must be >= 0. n: " + n);

   if(n<2){
       return Integer.toString(n);
   } else {
       return convBinary(n/2) + Integer.toString(n%2);
   }
}
```